# Add CardView Dynamically (With XML)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I was wondering. Is there a way to add CardViews to a RecyclerView with a button press?

What I mean is that can I add a CardView with this XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardrl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$MainFragment">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/CardView_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:elevation="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:text="@string/card_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And have it so that before it is created I can fill the TextView with data?

I know a lot people are going to say do something like this:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findById(R.id.rl);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
rl.addView(1, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_layout, this, false) );
```

but for some reason it won't work because it says `Cannot resolve method Inflate(int, activity, boolean)`

Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's no such thing as an `inflate(int, activity, boolean)` method.
It's supposed to be `inflate(int resId, Viewgroup parentContainer, boolean attachToParent)`

Comment: I figured that I'm just not sure why it thinks that my .xml file is an `int`

Comment: no, you're supposed to pass the container (or a null) in the `ViewGroup container` parameter. You're passing `this`, which is the instance of your activity. That's why it's not compiling.